# Visualise Gradient Condition for Convex Function.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a convex differentiable function. What is the best visual justification for the condition

$$f(x)\geq f(y)+\nabla f(y)\cdot(x-y),~~\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n.$$

Any pictures or hints are much appreciated.

Comment: It is relatively simple in one dimension: fix a point $p=(y,f(y))$ on the graph of $f$. If $f$ is convex then the slope of the tangent at $p$ is less than the slope of any secant passing through $p$.